# Sonata User Bundle + Admin Bundle admin redirect after login

Tags: sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata-user-bundle

I'm trying to make sonata work like this:

- if a regular user logs in he's redirected to "/" 

- if an admin logs in he's redirected to "/admin/dashboard"

I tried to make it with firewalls that are in app/config/security.yml and here's what i come to:

```
        # This firewall is used to handle the admin login area
        # This part is handled by the Sonata User Bundle
        admin:
        pattern:            /(.*)
        context:            user
        form_login:
            provider:       fos_userbundle
            login_path:     /login
            use_forward:    false
            check_path:     /login_check
            failure_path:   null
            default_target_path:   /admin/dashboard
        logout:
            path:           /admin/logout
            target:           /
        anonymous:    true

        # This firewall is used to handle the public login area
        # This part is handled by the FOS User Bundle
        main:
        pattern:      .*
        context:        user
        form_login:
            provider:       fos_userbundle
            login_path:     /login
            use_forward:    false
            check_path:     /login_check
            failure_path:   null
            default_target_path: /
            always_use_default_target_path:   true
        logout:
            path: /logout
            target: /
```

now every logged in user is redirected to /admin obviously throwing 'access denied' for non-admin users. 
Is there any way to fix it in this yml file or shall i search for some different way of checking user roles?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way to redirect user on basis of role you can implement your own authentication handler and check role of the user in `onAuthenticationSuccess()` function and redirect depending on the nature of user

```
namespace YourNamespace\YourBundle\Services;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;

class AuthenticationHandler implements  AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface {
    protected $container;

    public function __construct( $container ) {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess( Request $request, TokenInterface $token ) {
        $user = $token->getUser();
        if($user->isGranted( 'ROLE_ADMIN' )){
            $url = $this->container->get( 'router' )->generate( 'sonata_admin_dashboard' );
        }else{
            $url = $this->container->get( 'router' )->generate( 'your_welcome_route' );
        }
        return new RedirectResponse( $url );

    }
}
```

define service for your authentication handler

```
services:
    admin_success_handler:
        class: YourNamespace\YourBundle\Services\AuthenticationHandler
        arguments: [ '@service_container' ]
```

And in your firewall define `success_handler`

```
        admin:
        pattern:            /(.*)
        context:            user
        form_login:
            provider:       fos_userbundle
            login_path:     /login
            use_forward:    false
            check_path:     /login_check
            failure_path:   null
            default_target_path:   /admin/dashboard
            success_handler: admin_success_handler
        logout:
            path:           /admin/logout
            target:           /
        anonymous:    true
```